# Add option in React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am working in a ReactJS project where I am using [React Select](https://react-select.com/home). I am using multiselect option in my ReactJS dropdown. My code is like below.

```
<Select
    options={postValues}
    placeholder={"Select Post"}
    className="modal__input"
    isMulti={true}
    name={"post_id"}
    onChange={inputChange}
/>
```

I would like to add an option `Select All Values` which one will select all values.

[image]

How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you just add it to `postValues`?  Then in your `inputChange` logic you'd check to see if that "special" option was selected and handle your logic accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @David. But what will be logic to select all the values ?

Comment: Your "select all" option would be a hard-coded "magic value" (likely some constant somewhere, but you can define it however you like).  Your logic would check if the selected value is (or includes) that value.  If it does, you would treat the entire collection within `postValues` as being "selected".

Answer (score 1):

so you have write the logic into the onchange function which should be something like this.

```
handleChange(newSelection) {
    if (!newSelection.length) {
        this.setState({
            value: []
        });
        return;
    }

    // check if the last select was select all
    if (newSelection.at(-1).label === "select all") {
        this.setState({
            value: colourOptions
        });
        return;
    }

    this.setState({
        value: newSelection
    });
```